# activar elementos en varios formularios a la vez

Tags: javascript

Tengo una página con tres formularios. Todos los elementos vienen desactivados excepto el input que encabeza cada formulario. Necesito habilitar estos elementos de manera que activen  y desactiven cada formulario. Si fuese un solo formulario sería sencillo con document.form y un flujo de control, pero como son varios al mismo tiempo no he podido resolverlo. Adjunto viene el código.

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>cervezas</title>
        <style>
.formulario {
    margin-top: 5.5%;
    margin-left: 5.5%;
    margin-right: 5.5%;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.formulario.mahou {
    width: 25%;
}

.formulario.heineken {
    margin: auto;
    width: 25%;
}

.formulario.carlsberg {
    width: 25%;
}

.datos label {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.encabezado {
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%; 
}

select {
    width: 100%;
}

textarea {
    width: 98%;
}

input[type=submit] {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

input[type="text"]:disabled { 
    background: #E5E5E5; 
}

textarea:disabled {
    background: #E5E5E5; 
}

select:disabled {
    width: 100%;
    color: #BBBBBB;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

input[type=submit]:disabled {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    color: #BBBBBB;
    margin: auto;
}
        </style>
        </head>
<body>
    
    
<div class="formulario mahou">
<form name="mahou" method="post" action="">
 
<div class="encabezado">
    <input type="radio" name="cerveza" value="mahou">&nbsp;&nbsp;MAHOU
</div>
            
<div class ="datos">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" disabled>
 
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" disabled>

    <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
    <input type="text" name="telefono" disabled>
</div>

<div class="datos">
        <label for="vasos">Cuantos vasos tomas a la semana?:</label>
        <select name="vasos-mahou" disabled>
            <option value="m1">menos de 10</option>
            <option value="m2">menos de 20</option>
            <option value="m3">menos de 30</option>
            <option value="m4">menos de 40</option>
        </select>
</div>
        
<div class="datos">
        <label for="marca">Cómo te enteraste de la marca?</label>
        <textarea name="marca" disabled></textarea>
</div>
    
<div class="datos">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" disabled>
</div>
</form>
</div>
    
    
<div class="formulario heineken">
    <form name="heineken" method="post" action="">
 
<div class="encabezado">
    <input type="radio" name="cerveza" value="heineken">&nbsp;&nbsp;HEINEKEN
</div>
            
<div class ="datos">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" disabled>
 
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" disabled>

    <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
    <input type="text" name="telefono" disabled>
</div>

<div class="datos">
        <label for="vasos">Cuantos vasos tomas a la semana:</label>
        <select name="vasos-heineken" disabled>
            <option value="h1">menos de 10</option>
            <option value="h2">menos de 20</option>
            <option value="h3">menos de 30</option>
            <option value="h4">menos de 40</option>
        </select>
</div>
        
<div class="datos">
        <label for="marca">Cómo te enteraste de la marca?</label>
        <textarea name="marca" disabled></textarea>
</div>    


<div class="datos">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" disabled>
</div>
</form>
</div> 

    
<div class="formulario carlsberg">
     <form name="carlsberg" method="post" action="">
 
<div class="encabezado">
    <input type="radio" name="cerveza" value="carlsberg">&nbsp;&nbsp;CARLSBERG
</div>
            
<div class ="datos">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" disabled>
 
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" disabled>

    <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
    <input type="text" name="telefono" disabled>
</div>

<div class="datos">
        <label for="vasos">Cuantos vasos tomas a la semana:</label>
        <select name="vasos-carlsberg" disabled>
            <option value="c1">menos de 10</option>
            <option value="c2">menos de 20</option>
            <option value="c3">menos de 30</option>
            <option value="c4">menos de 40</option>
        </select>
</div>
         
<div class="datos">
        <label for="marca">Cómo te enteraste de la marca?</label>
        <textarea name="marca" disabled></textarea>
</div>             

<div class="datos">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" disabled>
</div>
</form>
</div>  
    
    
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el contenido de script.js?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema de diseño. Los formularios son exactamente iguales, lo único que cambia es el label del radio que los acompaña. Una solución mucho más limpia es tener un único formulario y poder decidir a qué marca corresponde por medio de un desplegable.

Por ejemplo:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body { background: #fff; }
.form {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 400px;
}
.form label {
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 15px;
}
.form header h3 {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.form .brand select {
  margin-left: 12px;
}
.form input[type="text"],
.form select,
.form textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  transition: box-shadow .15s ease;
}
.form input[type="text"]:focus,
.form select:focus,
.form textarea:focus {
  
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  outline: none;
}
.form .body {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 25px 20px;
}
.form .body .separator {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.form .form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.form .form-group:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.form .form-group label {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.form .action {
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: right;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: .5rem 1.15rem;
}
.btn i {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
.btn.primary {
  background-color: #16a085;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<article class="form">
    <header>
      <h3>Danos tu opinión</h3>
    </header>
    <section class="body">
      <section class="brand">
        <label for="brand">Marca:</label>
        <select id="brand">
          <option value="mahou">Mahou</option>
          <option value="heiniken">Heiniken</option>
          <option value="carlsberg">Carlsberg</option>
        </select>
      </section>
      <hr class="separator" />
      <form action="" id="beer-feedback">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Teléfono</label>
          <input type="text" id="phone" style="max-width: 150px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="qty">¿Cuántos vasos tomas a la semana?</label>
          <select id="qty" style="max-width: 150px">
            <option value="1">Menos de 10</option>
            <option value="2">Entre 10 y 20</option>
            <option value="3">Más de 30</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="know">¿Cómo conociste la marca?</label>
          <textarea id="know" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
        <section class="action">
          <button class="btn primary" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
            Enviar
          </button>
        </section>
      </form>
    </section>
  </article>
```

Ahora, para enviar el feedback al servidor tienes dos opciones. Hacerlo mediante AJAX o una petición normal. Hacerlo vía AJAX siempre es más [User Friendly](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34051/is-user-friendly-a-valid-term-in-user-experience). Te muestro las dos formas.

> **Atención:** Los códigos JavaScript colocados siguen la nomenclatura ES6. Es conveniente usar [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) para convertirlos a ES5 en orden de hacerlos cross-browser.

**Petición AJAX**

```
let feedbackForm = document.getElementById('beer-feedback');
feedbackForm.addEventListener('submit', onFeedback);

function onFeedback(e) {
  let brand = document.getElementById('brand').value;
  let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  let phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  let qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
  let know = document.getElementById('know').value;

  fetch(feedbackForm.getAttribute('action'), {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      name,
      phone,
      qty,
      know
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    alert('Gracias por darnos tu opinión');
  }).catch(() => {
    alert('Algo salió mal. Inténtelo nuevamente');
  });
}
```

**Petición normal**

```
let brandEl = document.getElementById('brand');
const ACTION_URL = feedbackForm.getAttribute('action');

brandEl.onChange = (e) => {
    feedbackForm.setAttribute('action', `${ACTION_URL}=${brandEl.value}`);
};
```

**NOTA** En el modo normal, se asume que el formulario tiene un valor para action de la siguiente forma: `/sendFeedback/beers?brand`. Es por eso que luego concatenamos con: `=${brandEl.value}`.

Answer (score 1):

Modifique un poco el código ya que no se puede tener varios radio button con el mismo nombre (name) en diferentes contenedores (div) y agregue unos estilos. A esta modificación tome parte del código de Neyer la del evento load de la ventana del navegador para ejecutar el proceso.

Lo ideal, en mi opinion, es tener la barra con los radio buttons y un solo formulario visible (el que este seleccionado) y mientras el usuario interacciona mostrar/ocultar el formulario que corresponda.

Aca dejo el fiddle: [Fiddle formularios](https://jsfiddle.net/da5yn9fz/)

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esto:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
    function init(){
        var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
        for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
            radios[i].addEventListener('click', seleccionar, false);
        }
    }

    function seleccionar(e){
        var nodos = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        for(var i = 0; i < nodos.length; i++){
            nodos[i].disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: El código que puse adjunto tiene un problema de jerarquía. Los input radio debieran estar fuera de los formularios para activar uno a la vez. El código de javascript hace referencia a esa jerarquía en e.target.parentNode.parentNode. Alguien me podría dar alguna ayuda para modificar la función seleccionar de manera de actuar sobre un formulario ligado a un input radio sin que haya parentesco entre estos dos elementos?